# How to draw a distribution of the function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}$ and $x\in[0,2]$.

How i can draw a distribution for it ?

Comment: Do you mean how to draw the density function?

Comment: Yes i mean density function.

Comment: Well, it's the constant line at height $\frac{1}{2}$ between $x=0$ and $x=2$.

Comment: If you mean how to draw the density function and I am not getting you wrong, it's simply to plot $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ along the given interval, that's all. Should get you a rectangle if you take into consideration the line $x=2$ and $x=0$. Not sure I get you right, though.

Comment: Okey, i needed to make $\int f(x)$ and plot for function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x$ in the interval $[0,2].

Comment: Ink, pencil or pen?

Answer (score 1):

A density is just like any other function. To plot it, simply draw $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ on the given interval $[0,2]$. This would be a zero slope line at $\frac{1}{2}$ on the vertical axis from $0$ to $2$ on the horizontal axis (including $0$ and $2$, obviously). Note that the vertical axis is the probability for a given element in the domain of the random variable whose density function we are considering. This is the density of a uniform random variable on $[0,2]$.